# How to do multi-column match in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
    A      B      C      D
  ------------------------------------
1 | Yes  | No   |      |      |      |
2 | 1    | 1    | 0    | 1    | 0    |
  ------------------------------------
  ------------------------------------
12| Yes  | No   |      | Yes  | Yes  |
13| Yes  | Yes  | No   | No   |      |
14| Yes  | No   |      | No   | Yes  |
15| No   | Yes  | No   | No   |      |
...
```

I want to fill the cells in Row 2 with a 1 or 0 depending on several criteria. The value should be 1 if all of the following are met (using cell D2 as a reference):

1. All previous values in Row 1 should match at least one entry in the table starting at D12. For cell D2, this means A1:C1 should exactly match columns A:C in at least one row of the table.
2. For any of the matching rows from #1, there should be a non-empty value in the same column as the cell being evaluated. So cell D2 would look for a non-empty value in Column D of any rows that match the criteria in #1.

If either of these conditions fails, the cell value should be 0. In Cell D2 we have a value of 1 because the algorithm finds a match in rows 12 and 14 and a non-empty cell in D12 and D14.

I'll need to be able to apply this dynamically across several columns so I'm trying to avoid writing a column-specific function. I realize I could probably write a UDF to perform this, but I wanted to avoid going that route if possible.

Comment: I don't understand why C2 is 0?

Comment: @TomSharpe C2 fails #2. It finds matches on Rows 12 and 14 but Column C for both of those rows is empty. I've edited the question to make that a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this was a challenge I had a go at it and came up with

```
=SIGN(SUM(--(MMULT(($A1:A1=$A12:A15)*(B12:B15<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A12:A15)^0))=COLUMNS($A1:A1))))
```

to be entered in B2 and pulled across. This has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

A2 I think is just

```
=sign(counta(a12:a15))
```

because it will be 1 unless the whole column is empty.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Works perfectly. I haven't used MMULT before. I'll have to read up on how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a complete answer to your problem as stated *without* a UDF, but I'd question the method a bit and say "why complicate with 'AND this column isn't blank (but could be any other value)?"

Why not just look for a row match from that field backward? Seems to me it would just shift things by a column, and in fact, this is exactly what you're doing in A2 anyway, since there's nothing before A. So matching on duplicate rows for example, D2 would contain basically the same information as your example has in C2.

To look for duplicates across fields, you could use something like this formula that would go in C2: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A3:A15=A1)*1,(B3:B15=B1)*1,(C3:C15=C1)*1)>1,1,0)`

In D2, you'd copy that formula and add `(D3:D15=D1)*1`, etc.

Comment: I attempted a SUMPRODUCT solution and it came out looking sorta like yours. The problem I have is that I want to generalize the function so that I can apply it across many columns. I'm trying to avoid having to manually add Column D (and Column E, F, etc.).